# Asynchronously POSTing parent-children objects and relationships (recursively?)

Tags: javascript, recursion, axios

Say I am trying to create a "family tree" as one JSON array.

So I have an array of `Person` objects.

Each `Person` object has a mandatory `name`. Each object can also optionally have a `children` field that contains an array of other `Person` objects (that also have a `children` field - so the "depth" of the family tree can essentially go on forever.)

If there is no children, the `children` field will just be an empty array `[]`.

E.g.

```js
  const family_name = "The Numbers";
  const family = [{
      name: "1"
      children: [],
    },
    {
      name: "2"
      children: [{
          name: "2 - 1",
          children: [],
        },
        {
          name: "2 - 2",
          children: [{
            name: "2 - 2 - 1",
            children: [],
          }, ],
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "3"
      children: [{
        name: "3 - 1",
        children: [],
      }, ],
    },
  ]
```

I need to POST the "parent" before the "child". When I POST a `Person`, I get its `id` back in the `response.data`. This `id` needs to be used in the immediate child's POST as a `parent_id` so that child will be associated to the parent.

I also need to POST the "family_name" first which will return a `family_id`. This `family_id` will be used as the `parent_id` for the very topmost `Person`s only.

e.g.

```js
axios.post(FAMILY_URL, {"family_name": family_name})
    .then((response) => {
        // Promise.all() POST 1, 2, and 3 with their "parent_id" as response.data.family_id
        // Promise.all() POST 2-1 and 2-2 with their "parent_id" as 2's response.data.id
        // POST 2-2-1 with its "parent_id" as 2-1's response.data.id
        // POST 3-1 with its "parent_id" as 3's response.data.id
    })
```

But what does the code look like if the number and depth of `Person` objects is unknown? I have to leverage a recursive function, right?

I would also like to use Promise.all() for all "siblings"

Comment: What data do you need to post? Do you need to include the `children` array in the post data?

Comment: Try to look up the bfs algorithm

Comment: The payload should be {"name": "", "parent_id": ""} where the created ```Person```'s ```id``` is returned whenever a ```Person``` is created via POST.

Comment: @MikeK.Shum OP isn't _searching_ though 

Comment: What do you need the end result to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to recursively *walk* the data structure, accumulating promises along the way

```js
// fake axios, ignore this bit
const FAMILY_URL="family-url",axios={post:async(a,o)=>(console.log(`POST ${a}`,o),{data:{id:`${a===FAMILY_URL?"":`${o.parent_id}-`}${Math.ceil(100*Math.random())}`}})};

// resolves an individual person by posting their details with a given
// parent ID, then doing the same for any children
const savePerson = async (parent_id, { name, children }) => {
  // get this person's ID
  const { data: { id } } = await axios.post("person-url", {
    name,
    parent_id
  })
  
  return {
    id, // assign the ID for visibility
    name,
    // pass this person's ID as the children's parent
    children: await savePeople(id, children)
  }
}

// resolves an array of people given a "parent ID"
const savePeople = (parent_id, people) =>
  Promise.all(people.map(person => savePerson(parent_id, person)))

// Top-level family helper
const saveFamily = async (family_name, family) => {
  const { data: { id } } = await axios.post(FAMILY_URL, { family_name })
  
  // resolve all the people in the family array
  return savePeople(id, family)
}

// minified
const family = [{"name":"1","children":[]},{"name":"2","children":[{"name":"2 - 1","children":[]},{"name":"2 - 2","children":[{"name":"2 - 2 - 1","children":[]}]}]},{"name":"3","children":[{"name":"3 - 1","children":[]}]}]

saveFamily("Smith", family).then(console.info)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it using the BFS algorithm.
Example:

```
function postFamily(family) {

    const queue = [];
    queue.unshift(...family);

    while (queue.length) {
        const cur = queue.pop();

        // HERE IS YOUR LOGIC RELATED TO THE CURRENT NODE
        // FOR EXAMPLE:
        axios.post('*FAMILY URL*', cur);

        for (const child of cur) {
            queue.unshift(child);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't clearly understand the wanted result, but i'm glad if it would help. Have a nice day!

Comment: This is a good, non-recursive option but you'll find it hard to keep track of which `parent_id` to apply to the child records